# Unable to install activator (play 2.3.x)

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to install Activator on my Windows PC and I get errors, here is the log:

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.5

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\abdollab\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.activator\activator-launcher\1.3.5\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.5!activator-launcher.jar:

      C:\Users\abdollab\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.activator\activator-launcher\1.3.5\jars\activator-launcher.jar

    ==== activator-launcher-local: tried

      file:////C:/activator/repository/com.typesafe.activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/activator-launcher-1.3.5.pom

      -- artifact com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.5!activator-launcher.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/activator-launcher-1.3.5.jar

    ==== typesafe-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/activator-launcher-1.3.5.pom

      -- artifact com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.5!activator-launcher.jar:

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/activator-launcher-1.3.5.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/ivys/ivy.xml

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.5: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/activator-launcher-1.3.5.pom

    Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/activator-launcher-1.3.5.jar

    Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/activator-launcher-1.3.5.pom

    Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/activator-launcher-1.3.5.jar

    Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/ivys/ivy.xml


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
java.lang.RuntimeException: not found
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:238)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:292)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:714)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.getDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:594)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:234)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Update.scala:106)
    at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$4.call(Update.scala:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Update.scala:101)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:352)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$retrieve$1(Launch.scala:208)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:216)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getAppProvider0(Launch.scala:216)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:196)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:238)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:147)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:145)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$.error(Pre.scala:26)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Update.scala:106)
    at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$4.call(Update.scala:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Update.scala:101)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:352)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$retrieve$1(Launch.scala:208)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:216)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getAppProvider0(Launch.scala:216)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:196)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:238)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:147)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:145)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
```

first about this specific part:

```
    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/activator-launcher-1.3.5.pom

      -- artifact com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.5!activator-launcher.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/activator-launcher-1.3.5.jar

    ==== typesafe-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/activator-launcher-1.3.5.pom

      -- artifact com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.5!activator-launcher.jar:

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.5/activator-launcher-1.3.5.jar
```

if I copy paste any of these links in my browser, I get a NOT FOUND page in return! why these files do not exist anymore??

Comment: Are you on a corporate network behind a proxy server perhaps? Are you using the Activator package downloaded from Typesafe?

Comment: about the activator package: its an older version from playframework.com, (I have the same problem with the newest version). And I was using a company laptop but with a private internet connection. these links that I mentioned above work nowhere. @Nio

Comment: @Nio I just realized that the activator version in the typesafe website is about 500mb, so I guess it should have all the dependencies?

Comment: behzad, ye if you grab the full package then that will save pulling down resources later. however, when you run Activator it will still try and connect to the internet to check versions etc so if you still see issues like `Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException` then it may because you are behind a proxy and not authenticating to get out thru it.

Comment: I also think that it's because of a proxy, but things are a little messy if you have a previous installation of Play on your computer.

You should try to delete ~/.ivy2 and ~/sbt and try again

Comment: I have exactly the same problem... no activator version works, and I'm not behind a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it. The problem was the JDK. My Ubuntu box had OpenJDK-8 installed on it... but the activator doesn't work with it (don't ask me why). Eventually I just removed OpenJDK-8 and installed Oracle's Java 8. Now it works.